# GridLayoutManager gravity right

Tags: android, gridview, right-to-left

I am using RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager to show item on Grid View, but I want to align this item to right means if there is an empty cell on a row, this empty cell should be on the left.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fill RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920867/how-can-i-fill-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-from-right-to-left)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:gravity="end"`.

Comment: Please, edit the answer, cause it looks more like a comment, which makes  it a good candidate for deletion.

Comment: But I have enough reputation to `Recommend deletion` while reviewing low quality posts, which I did not, btw, for your answer, gently informing that the answer's in the queue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Custom `GridLayoutManager` to fill items from right to left.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class RtlGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {
    public RtlGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public RtlGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    public RtlGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isLayoutRTL() {
        return true;
    }
}
```