# How can I fill RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager from right to left

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, right-to-left, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to fill some data into a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```

This will fill the data into the grid from **left to right**. The first item will be put into top-left place, etc.

But the app I'm developing is designed for an RTL language, so I need to make it fill from **right to left**.

I tried to change the last argument to `true`. But it just scrolled the `RecyclerView` all the way down.

Also setting `layoutDirection` attribute for `RecyclerView` doesn't work (without considering that my min API is 16 and this attribute is added for API17+):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

How can I create a right to left filled grid using `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Kindly try using android:rotationY="180" first

Comment: you can achieve this by animation..

Comment: please check this answer:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728837/recyclerview-grow-element-from-right-to-left/46315909#46315909)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728837/recyclerview-grow-element-from-right-to-left

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Create a class that extends `GridLayoutMAnager` ,and override the `isLayoutRTL()` method like this:

```
public class RtlGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

    public RtlGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public RtlGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    public RtlGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isLayoutRTL(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad! Solved the problem beautifully.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, [`isLayoutRTL()`](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#isLayoutRTL()) is a documented protected method of **GridLayoutManager**, therefore this solution is forward-compatible.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, that was great.

Comment: Consider to use RecyclerView 24.2.0 and upper for better results. According to [GridLayoutManager documentation] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.html#getSpanIndex()) RTL handling is better than before. I had some issues before on calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: is it safe to use? Doesn't need API 17+ ?

Comment: thanks it worked .
if we have to write class so what's the job of android:layoutDirection="rtl"?

Answer (score 14):

The answer by Mohammad is true but you do not need to create a new class. you can simply override isLayoutRTL method.

```
GridLayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2) {
    @Override
    protected boolean isLayoutRTL() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a better way to do it

You can programmatically change the layout direction of the RecycleView

```
workHourRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.market_hours_recycler);
workHourRecycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),4));

//Programtically set the direction
workHourRecycler.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: It works fine, you juste have to call `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(workHourRecycler, View. LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)`

Comment: `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(View, int)`  does nothing on api < 17. Using ViewCompat just makes it so it doesn't throw an exception on api levels that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, GridLayouManager should [fill rows from right](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.java#L540) when `getLayoutDirection()` gives `ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL`. Normally, this direction will be inherited from the `RecyclerView's` container.

But if this does not work as expected, or you need to push it down to API 16, or you some device with bad implementation of RTL support, you can simply pull the `GridLayoutManager` from github, and use a custom manager that you tune to your liking.

It may be enough to extend the stock `GridLayoutManager` and override [layoutChunk()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.java#L356).

Comment: I can't override it as it is package-visible. Also I couldn't find where this method is being used. But it seems promising.

Comment: What can prevent you from starting your custom manager with statement `package android.support.v7.widget;`?

Comment: Thanks Alex. Didn't know that. It was actually very easy to bypass the issue. Thanks for the clues.

Answer (score -6):

Its very simple, just call method `setReverseLayout` as,

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: This will just make it upside-down!